# how to prevent sql injection at login

Tags: codeigniter-3

How to add SQL injection functions to the admin login?

C_Log_Funtion

```
function index(){
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $username = $this->input->post('a');
            $password = hash("sha512", md5($this->input->post('b')));
            $cek = $this->model_app->cek_login($username,$password,'users');
            $row = $cek->row_array();
            $total = $cek->num_rows();
            if ($total > 0){
                $this->session->set_userdata('upload_image_file_manager',true);
                $this->session->set_userdata(array('username'=>$row['username'],
                                   'level'=>$row['level'],
                                   'id_session'=>$row['id_session']));

                redirect('administrator/home');
            }else{
                $data['title'] = 'Username or Password salah!';
                $this->load->view('administrator/view_login',$data);
            }
        }else{
            $data['title'] = 'Administrator &rsaquo; Log In';
            $this->load->view('administrator/view_login',$data);
        }
    }
```

I made a function like this but got an injection, is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently trying to add a codeigniter default security function to the form

> security->sanitize_filename

```
$username = $this->security->sanitize_filename($this->input->post('a',TRUE));
$password = $this->security->sanitize_filename(hash("sha512", md5($this->input->post('b',TRUE))));
```

until now there has been no injection on my website.